# Why is greedy decoding outperforming beam decoding for a CTC network?

Tags: tensorflow, decoding, sequences

I trained a TensorFlow model using the CTC loss.

I decoded the network output using `tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder`, and got an average edit distance of 0.437 over a batch of 1000 sequences.

I decoded the network output using `tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder`, and for the following beam widths, got the following average edit distances:

width 1: 0.48953804

width 4: 0.4880197

width 100: 0.48801425

My question is: since beam width = 1 is equivalent to greedy decoding, shouldn't the accuracy be the same? And why is beam search decoding performing worse than greedy decoding?

Comment: could you check which samples perform worse with beam than with greedy search? 
Is it possible that repeated labels have been merged with beam search (e.g. Helo instead of Hello). 
If yes: set merge_repeated=False for beam search.
The meaning of merge_repeated differs for greedy and beam search.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, that solved my problem.